# Why won't these social buttons centre in responsive design?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, centering

We've manually programmed Twitter, Facebook and G+ buttons on our site which uses responsive design in a ajax portfolio. They all align with each other perfectly but the problem is we want all 3 to be centred no matter what the size of the surrounding container.

In my head this should work easily with a surrounding Div that has 100% width to expand to the portfolio size, inside that another Div which has margin-left and margin-right as auto which floats centrally to the 100% width div and then inside of that div the containers for the buttons. However for some reason they always hard align to the left. Here is my code at the moment.

Here is an example

```
http://themixtapesite.com/#/joe-budden-a-lose-quarter
```

now change your browser window to make it smaller so you can dynamically see all the different sizes - I want those social buttons to float centred in the middle rather than on the left like they are now..

```
<!-- Social sharing buttons -->
    <div class="social-single">

    <div class="social-centre">     

    <div class="twit-button"><a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-via="mixtapes_4_free" data-lang="msa" data-related="realdannys" data-hashtags="mixtape">Tweet</a></div>

    <div class="fb-button"><iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink($post->ID)); ?>&amp;title=<?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?>&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=71&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=21&amp;appId=118471234925480" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width: 71px; height: 21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
                        </div>

    <div class="gplus-button"><g:plusone href="<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink($post->ID)); ?>" size="medium" annotation="bubble" width="50px"></g:plusone></div>

    </div> </div>
```

And the CSS

```
/* Social Buttons */

.social-single {
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
width:  100% !important;
}

.social-centre
{
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

.twit-button {
float:  left;
margin: 0;
margin-right: 5px;
width: 80px;
}

.fb-button {
float: left;
margin: 0;
width: 80px;
}

.gplus-button {
float: left;
margin: 0;
width: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already used `margin-left: auto;` and `margin-right:auto;` it is good.
You have all things set in the way of responsiveness.
But one thing that browser checks for every element, its `width` as well as `height` . 
We should define these values separately, otherwise it'll assume it without having any child element inside it.

I've checked your code and as i think you will have to add only one thing - give `.social-centre` class width whatever you want but it would be good if it is in %'s for its responsiveness.

```
.social-centre
{
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width:50%; //example, whatever you want.
}
```

And it'll work properly. Hope it'll help you.

Comment: Hmm, I tried it at width 90% but unfortunately not, you can see an example here, `http://themixtapesite.com/#/joe-budden-a-lose-quarter` now change your browser window to make it smaller so you can dynamically see all the different sizes - I want those social buttons to float centred in the middle rather than on the left like they are now...

Comment: hey, Danny just re-check you code. You have used body tag more than once, browser's assuming everything end upto first body tag. Just remove first closening body tag. its inside .social-center class. If possible try to maintain your code more semantic than now. your have used scripts/style in between page, that is not appropriate in W3C guidelines.

Comment: Akshaya, not sure what you mean by using the body tag more than once? Its only once in my source and all the content is in the middle. Are you looking at the source? In which case you'd need to look at the source of the ajax page as source of the main page will just give you the navigation grid…

Other that that there are no body tags in my php for the portfolio (with the social buttons in) its all Wordpress with ajax. and the div tags all terminate in the right places…?

Comment: Oh! so it may be wordpress issue (body tags). Anyway i've tried that code in my IDE and it worked properly. Just check your code twice otherwise and one thing if you ain't so sure about Wordpress theme customization you can put those CSS properties via Javascript or Jquery. You can check Display:inline-block; or Display:inline-table; . Also use margin properties in percentages.

Comment: the problem I'm getting is that it has to be a different width percentage depending on the responsive layout. For desktop 90%, then it goes to iPad/landscape sizes and 50% works perfectly here (its no problem setting them separately as I can do that in the responsive CSS) the problem is when I get to smartphone sizes, for most of them 50% is perfect, but then when you get to the smaller sizes 50% width is too narrow and it knocks one of the icons to the next line. I tried setting a minimum px width but then the div is off center again...

Comment: On mobile viewports just remove unnecessary margins-paddings from those social boxes(icons). And check if total width of those social buttons doesn't exceed the parent element.